# Docker - overlay network on rhel 7

Tags: networking, docker

We are running docker 1.9 on rhel7 in test/prod. (installed from docker official repos)

Would like to use the overlay-network driver, but it requires kernel 3.16  according to the [getting started guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/). 
RHEL7 runs a 3.10 kernel.

What are my options for using the docker overlay network driver with RHEL7?

I have tested [flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel), but in my understandig flannel is external from docker, thus not being controlled via the `docker network` cli commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker engine 1.10 will support overlay network on 3.10+ kernels according to the releasenotes of the first RC

https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.10.0-rc1

Answer (score 0):

One option is to install a recent kernel through the Elrepo repository (http://elrepo.org). 
A quick start guide is available at http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-install-recent-stable-kernel/.

However, the new kernel will avoid any Red Hat support.

Comment: I am aware of the elrepo alternative, but this is not an option because of our policy to run supported rhel.